# Linear approximation in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Let $f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^3}$. Find the linear approximation at the point $(3, 2, 6)$. Use it to approximate $\sqrt{(3.02)^2 + (1.97)^2 + (5.99)^2}$.

What's going on here? I cannot find anything online to use a linear approximation for $3$ variables. For $2$ variable functions it's just the case $L(x, y) = f(a, b) + f_x (a, b) (x - a) + f_y (a, b) (y - b)$, but this seems to be different for functions like this from $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$? Should I find the Jacobian here and use that in the place of the partials or what? I hope it's not just the case where I add another term to the $2$ variable one $L(x, y) = f(a, b) + f_x (a, b) (x - a) + f_y (a, b) (y - b) +f_z (a, b) (z - b)$...

Comment: Did you mean $L(x,y,\color{red}z)=f(a,b,\color{red}c)+f_x(a,b,\color{red}c)(x-a)+\cdots(z-\color{red}c)$?

Comment: It's a very important point that the derivative of a  function (multiple variables or otherwise) is defined as the best linear approximation to the function at that point.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I did...

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is the case when you add another term.

$f(3,2,6)=\sqrt{49}=7\\$

$f_x(x,y,z)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\\$

$f_y(x,y,z)=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\\$

$f_z(x,y,z)=\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\\$

$L(x,y,z)=f(a,b,c)+f_x(a,b,c)(x-a)+f_y(a,b,c)(y-b)+f_z(a,b,c)(z-c)$

$f_x(3,2,6)=\frac{3}{7},f_y(3,2,6)=\frac{2}{7},f_z(3,2,6)=\frac{6}{7}$

$L(3.02,1.97,5.99)=7+\frac{3}{7}*0.02+\frac{2}{7}*-0.03+\frac{6}{7}*-0.01=7-\frac{0.06}{7}$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.   I think you left out a multiplication symbol in the last line

Comment: Thank you for noticing.

Answer (score 1):

You are right in thinking you can just use a Jacobian style derivative! Let $f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = f(\vec{x})$ for a column vector $\vec{x}$ and let your point of evaluation be given as $\vec{x}_0 = \begin{bmatrix} 3\\2\\6\end{bmatrix}.$ Note that for this system, the Jacobian style derivative is $$J = \frac{\partial f}{\partial (x_1,x_2,x_3)} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} & \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_3}\end{bmatrix} = \nabla f(\vec{x})$$

which is of course a row vector. This means we can write the first order linearization and make it look the "same" as it did in one variable by saying

$$L(\vec{x}_0) = f(\vec{x}_0) + \nabla f(\vec{x}_0)(\vec{x}-\vec{x}_0).$$

Now we have written an expression that works for any function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.